# Word document in HTML page does not display toolbars

Tags: ms-word

I have a requirement to display dynamically generated word document on the server in an html page
I tried using the OBJECT tag and the document was indeed displayed correct. But the toolbars like print, file etc are missing. 
Note: secondary requirement is to enable the user to print the contents of the word document displayed, so the print toolbar is essential for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is actually possible. When you use the `<object>` tag, Word is being invoked to render the document, but you don't actually have a full-fledged instance of Word running in the browser. I doubt that there's any way to get Word to display its UI inside the `<object>` area.

You may have to write some javascript to invoke the browser's print capabilities.